# Modify existing value in dictionary (or defaultdictionary) by incrementing that value

Tags: python, dictionary, count, defaultdict

I would like to keep a counter for every time a particular value comes up in the list I am scanning.

For example:
list:

```
[(a, 0.2), (b, 1), (a, 0.2), (a, 1)]
```

I would like a dictionary that can show the following:

`mydict = {"a": (# val below 1, # val equal to 1), ...}`

Therefore:
`mydict = {"a": (2, 1), "b" :(0, 1)}`

Is there a way to do this with a default dictionary or normal dictionary?

Should I do something like:
`mydict[mydict["a"]+1]` for every value I see either below or equal to 1?

Comment: I don't understand how the expected output is obtained from the input

Comment: 0.2 and 0.2 are less than 1, therefore the first value in "a" : 2,1 is 2. The other a  1, is equal to 1, so the second value of the tuple "a" : 2,1 is 1.   Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, assuming the type of input is an array of arrays and you can store the results as an array in your dictionary, here is how it could be done.

```
# Define list of numbers
lettersNumbersList = [["a", 0.2], ["b", 1], ["a", 0.2], ["a", 1]]

# Here is the dictionary you will populate.
numberOccurences = {}

# This function is used to increment the numbers depending on if they are less
# than or greater than one.
def incrementNumber(letter, number):

    countingArray = numberOccurences[letter]

    if number < 1:
        countingArray[0] = countingArray[0] + 1
    elif number >= 1:
        countingArray[1] = countingArray[1] + 1

    return(countingArray)

# Loops through all of the list, gets the number and letter from it. If the letter
# is already in the dictionary then increments the counters. Otherwise starts 
# both from zero.
for item in lettersNumbersList:

    letter = item[0]
    number = item[1]

    if letter in numberOccurences:
        numberOccurences[letter] = incrementNumber(letter, number)

    else:
        numberOccurences[letter] = [0, 0]
        numberOccurences[letter] = incrementNumber(letter, number)

print(numberOccurences)
```

Comment: This works well! Thank you very much!! Really stellar.

Answer (score 1):

This should be faster than the other solution (also, very clean and Pythonic IMHO):

```
mylist = [("a", 0.2), ("a", 0.9), ("b", 1), ("a", 1)]

mydict = dict(mylist)

for k in mydict.keys():
    mydict[k] = (len([t for t in mylist if t[0]==k and t[1]<1]),
                 len([t for t in mylist if t[0]==k and t[1]==1]))

# >>> mydict
# {'a': (2, 1), 'b': (0, 1)}
```